# Is it okay to run kafka broker without replication in production

Tags: apache-kafka

We are considering to use kafka as low latency messaging solution for a financial real time trading application

Assuming that we use high quality hardware and dont expect the hardware/OS to fail, would it still be a risk if we run the broker without any replication

As replication will increase latency, also we want the data to be delivered in produced order without gap

Comment: It is always a risk, to run without any replication. It is always a good to have replication. As a designer and developer you should always assume worst case scenario and not the best case scenario. Hardware failure is only one part of it. What if your hardware gets corrupted due to manual error or power loss? You cannot predict such hardware failures. On a side note: replication won't increase any significant latency from consumer point of view.

Comment: Thanks but end to end latency will increase as producer will need to get acks from broker for order and gapless guarantees

Comment: replication factor 1 means just only leader will commit correct? no backup or does it mean 2 copies

Comment: Oops. that was typo.. you can always start with minimum factor of 3. So that you can tolerate 1 hardware/broker failure. And having replication factor of 3 should not add any significant latency(depending on how much batch.size and queue you are allowing for your producer)

Comment: Targeting low latency, max wait time is 0 ms

Comment: FWIW, you might want to checkout Hyperledger Fabric https://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/release-1.4/blockchain.html && https://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/release-1.4/kafka.html?highlight=kafka

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hardware can always fail. Don't assume it won't

You can set topic replication as higher than 1, but you seem to actually be wanting just `acks=1` or `acks=0` for low-latency producer requests. Replication happens in the backgrond, it will not slow down your requests from the leader partitions until you have a higher setting (`acks=all`)

However, if you have financial data, I would hope that is highly sensitive  and can not have packet loss under any conditition, so I would encourage you to reconsider having `acks=all`, `unclean.leader.election=false`, and `min.insync.replicas=2`.

Comment: Thanks. @cricket_007 Do you recommend using Idempotent producer mode because I want the data to be stored exactly once and gapless and in order at the broker. This kind of slows down as the max inflight requests to broker can only be 5. Also with 2 min.insync.replicas and idempotent producer I am seeing average latency on a 100k message burst to be about 20ms to 30ms.

Comment: I don't have experience using those settings, since they are realtively new, and not running Kafka broker version that supports them anyway.